# Passing $(this) selector into nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a script in place that needs to go through each `P` tag within a parent `DIV` with the class name of `entry-content` and translate each one using the google translate API.

So when a user clicks a link to translate the page from english to spanish this function is run:

```
function spanish() {
$(".entry-content p").each(function(){
      var text = $(this).html();
        google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
          google.language.translate(text, "en", "es", function(result) {
           if (result.translation) {
                alert($(this).html());  //outputs NULL
                $(this).html(result.translation); //doesn't work
            }
          });
        });
      });
}
```

The problem is when iIget to the inner function `$(this).html()` comesback NULL and I am not able to change the current elements html in order to change it to the new translated text.

So I guess my question is: 
How would I pass the current selected element into the nested functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may store it in a local variable

The value of `this` will always relate to the context in which the function is called. In your example, you're passing a function to `google.language.translate`, and so presumably, it is `google.language.translate` that calls that function.

However, if you store the value of `$(this)` when it is your `p`, you will be able to use that variable from the callback function.

```
function spanish() {
    $(".entry-content p").each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var text = $this.html();
        google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
          google.language.translate(text, "en", "es", function(result) {
           if (result.translation) {
                alert($this.html());  //outputs NULL
                $this.html(result.translation); //doesn't work
            }
          });
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: Seems so obvious now, thank you. as a sub question can I ask why use the $? whats the difference between  var $this = $(this);  and  var this = $(this);

Comment: well, `this` is a reserved keyword. You still won't be able to set that and access it from outside. `var anythingElse = $(this)` would work, and you may feel free to do whatever. `$this` has become a little bit of a convention for indicating "a jQuery wrapped 'this'", but you can use whatever you feel like.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` changes context in that callback, just keep a reference to the element/object you want, like this:

```
function spanish() {
  $(".entry-content p").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).html(), self = this;
    google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
      google.language.translate(text, "en", "es", function(result) {
       if (result.translation) {
            $(self).html(result.translation);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save a record of 'this' in the proper context - otherwise `this` refers to the inner function, not the parent function.

```
function spanish() {
$(".entry-content p").each(function(){

      // Save a record of 'this' in the proper context.
      var me = this;

      var text = $(this).html();
        google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
          google.language.translate(text, "en", "es", function(result) {
           if (result.translation) {
                alert($(me).html());  
                $(me).html(result.translation); 
            }
          });
        });
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this. Then research closures to understand what it's doing.

```
function spanish() {
$(".entry-content p").each(function(){
var $this = this; // new
      var text = $(this).html();
        google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
          google.language.translate(text, "en", "es", function(result) {
           if (result.translation) {
                alert($(this).html());  //outputs NULL
                $this.html(result.translation); 
            }
          });
        });
      });
}
```